# "Prodigal" vs. "spendthrift"

Tags: differences, nouns, adjectives

What are the differences between the words *prodigal* and *spendthrift*? They seem to mean the same.

When does one choose to use one over the other?

Comment: Have you looked them up? The dictionaries provide a distinction.

Comment: They're a lot closer in meaning than I had imagined. My sense is that the word _prodigal_ is so closely connected with the Biblical parable of the prodigal son that it carries a sense of dereliction in one's duties along with the monetary wastefulness (or recklessness) that the prodigal has in common with the garden-variety spendthrift.

Comment: Horrendous vs horrid.

Comment: Why is this closed? The guy has already said "they seem to mean the same" so looking in a dictionary is obviously not going to help.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary definitions show that the words are *very* similar. Especially in the sense that they are using each other to define themselves:

> [prodigal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prodigal) — adjective
>
> - wastefully or recklessly extravagant: prodigal expenditure.
> - giving or yielding profusely; lavish (usually followed by of  or with  ): prodigal of smiles; prodigal with money.
> - lavishly abundant; profuse: nature's prodigal resources.
>
> prodigal — noun
>
> - a person who spends, or has spent, his or her money or substance with wasteful extravagance; **spendthrift**.
>
> ---
>
> [spendthrift](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spendthrift?s=t) — noun
>
> - a person who spends possessions or money extravagantly or wastefully; **prodigal**.
>
> spendthrift — adjective
>
> - wastefully extravagant; **prodigal**.

The only real difference I notice is that "prodigal" can mean *having* or *giving* abundance instead of merely *spending* in abundance. The examples of "prodigal with smiles" and "nature's prodigal resources" wouldn't quite fit properly if you used "spendthrift":

> ? spendthrift with smiles
>
> ? nature's spendthrift resources

Answer (score 0):

Words rarely have the same meaning, because if that occurs one or other drops out of use.

*Prodigal* connotes wayward or reckless, not being sensible, and with a suggestion of reform (as in the prodigal son) but *spendthrift* connotes moral worthlessness. Somebody spending (too) lavishly on impressing friends or clients would be prodigal. Somebody blowing the family fortune in a casino would be a spendthrift.

Comment: To be fair, I often consider *spendthrift* to mean wayward or reckless and consider *prodigal* to mean false humility or false achievement; if simply because the only context I've heard it in (on TV, not personally) is a sarcastic "The prodigal son returns!". Which makes me wonder if an increasingly secular society will adjust the meaning of the word towards its sarcastic or colloquial implications over time.